# Sum up the number of words frequency using FreqDist, python

Tags: python, nltk, frequency-distribution

How to sum up the number of words frequency using fd.items() from FreqDist?

```
>>> fd = FreqDist(text) 
>>> most_freq_w = fd.keys()[:10] #gives me the most 10 frequent words in the text
>>> #here I should sum up numbers of each of these 10 freq words appear in the text
```

e.g. if each word in `most_freq_w` appear 10 times, the result should be `100`

**!!!** I don't need that number of all words in the text, just the 10 most frequent

Comment: Think (this is almost insultingly simple). Or at least show us what you tried.

Comment: What I tried is to get `fd.items` out of the `most_freq_w` - but that is absolutely wrong because the result is `0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `nltk`, but since `FreqDist` derives from `dict`, then the following should work:

```
v = fd.values()
v.sort()
count = sum(v[-10:])
```

Comment: note: `FreqDist` already returns its values sorted in decreasing order i.e., `count = sum(fd.values()[:10])` produces the same result as the above.

Answer (score 2):

To find the number of times a word appears in the corpus(your piece of text):

```
raw="<your file>"
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(raw)
fd = FreqDist(tokens)
print fd['<your word here>']
```

Answer (score 2):

It has a pretty print feature

```
    fd.pprint()
```

will do it.

Answer (score 0):

If `FreqDist` is a mapping of words to their frequencies:

```
sum(map(fd.get, most_freq_w))
```